# Skipping last N rows with lapply and then read.csv

Tags: r, lapply, readlines

I'm an R beginner and trying to read in a number of csv files, remove/skip the last 5 rows from each one, and then rbind them together. I can't figure out which step to do the removal of the rows and what function to use? I've tried `readLines` below and then tried to use nrow, but I'm pretty sure its in the wrong place.

This was what I started with:

```
alldata <- do.call(rbind, lapply(list.files(path = "./savedfiles", full.names = TRUE), read.csv))
```

I wasn't sure where to remove the rows in that code so I split it up to understand it and try to use `readLines`:

```
files<- list.files(path = "./savedfiles", full.names = TRUE)
c <- lapply(files, readLines) - to count the rows
alldata<- do.call(rbind,lapply(files, nrow = length(f) - 5, full.names = TRUE), read.csv)
```

This is just throwing an error that argument FUN is missing, so I know I'm not doing it right but not sure how to fix it.

Comment: I would do this in a couple steps. `alldata<-data.frame(); for (i in filelist){input<-read.csv(i); #todo cut off last five rows from input; alldata<-rbind(alldata, input);}`

Comment: It may be easier to read all the CSV files into a data frame with a column containing ID for each file. Then you can `dplyr::group_by` the ID and remove the last 5 lines using _e.g._ `dplyr::slice`.

Comment: Also, you might like the enhanced functions `dplyr::bind_rows()` and `readr::read_csv()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should put you on the right track. This reads the files first, then removes last 5 rows, and finally binds them together. Would also suggest not to use variable names that might conflict with function names. `files` and `c` are functions in base R. Here, I am using `all_files` instead of `files`. -

```
all_files <- list.files(path = "./savedfiles", full.names = TRUE)

do.call(rbind, # assuming columns match 1:1; use dplyr::bind_rows() if not 1:1
  lapply(all_files, function(x) {
    head(read.csv(x, header = T, stringsAsFactors = F), -5) # change as per needs
  })
)
```

Comment: thank you!! The function in the lapply was the thing I was missing. This worked great, I wasn't sure if I could do negative in head() either..(i actually tried tail() as well but that didn't work). Also thanks for calling out the lazy naming!

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` functions you can do

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

all_files <- list.files(path = "./savedfiles", full.names = TRUE)
map_df(all_files, ~read.csv(.x) %>% slice(seq_len(n()-5)))
```